# замена букв в строке

Tags: ассемблер

сделал замену чётных символов с аски на *, но вот сижу думаю как сделать нечётные.Учу асм недавно.Буду рад помощи)

```
    lea edi,rez
    td:
    mov al, [edi]
    and al, 1h
    cmp al, 0
    jnz l1
    mov al, [edi]
    cmp al, 65
    jb l1
    cmp al,122
    ja l1
    cmp al, 91
    jb l2
    cmp al, 96
    ja l2
    jmp l1
    l2:
    mov al, '*'
    mov [edi], al
    l1:
    inc edi
    mov al, [edi]
    cmp al, 0
    jnz td
    invoke MessageBox,0, addr rez, addr sztitle,MB_OK
    ret
```

Comment: Во-первых у вас замена не четный символов, а символов с четным кодом (смысл последующих проверок кодов символов не ясен). Во-вторых, для замены по нечетному коду символа замените `jnz l1` на `jz l1`.

Comment: И проверку на конец строки лучше делать в самом начале тела цикла (строка на входе может быть изначально пустой).